# Opening form with subforms with whereCondition

Tags: vba, ms-access, subform, openform

I have a form with values `dateFrom` and `dateTo`.
On click of button i want to open a new form which contains two subforms. One of the subforms shows filtered records. It shows the records that have `note_date` in range between `dateFrom` and `dateTo`.

`note_date` is one of the columns in query which is Record Source in the filtered subform

So what doesnt work is the filter for one of the subforms.

Here is my code how i thought it would work

`Overview_of_vacation_notes` is the name of the form that contains two subforms

```
dtmFrom = Text56.Value 'start date
dtmTo = Text58.Value   'end date
Dim strCriteria As String

strCriteria = "[note_date] >= #" & Format(dtmFrom, "yyyy-mm-dd") & "# AND [note_date] <= #" & Format(dtmTo, "yyyy-mm-dd") & "#"
    
DoCmd.OpenForm "Overview_of_vacation_notes", whereCondition:=strCriteria
```

Is there a way i could do something like this?

`DoCmd.OpenForm "Overview_of_vacation_notes", subformName.whereCondition:=strCriteria`

Because my code doesn't work cause of the whereCondition using the `strCriteria` on the main form and not the subform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DoCmd.OpenForm "Overview_of_vacation_notes"` is opening parent form. So, you can not apply where condition to subform to this line. You need to set filter criteria to subform and filter that subform to show filtered data. Try below codes.

```
dtmFrom = Text56.Value 'start date
dtmTo = Text58.Value   'end date
Dim strCriteria As String

strCriteria = "[note_date] >= #" & Format(dtmFrom, "yyyy-mm-dd") & "# AND [note_date] <= #" & Format(dtmTo, "yyyy-mm-dd") & "#"
    
DoCmd.OpenForm "Overview_of_vacation_notes"
Forms![Overview_of_vacation_notes]![YourSubform].Form.FilterOn = False 'Clear previous filter.
Forms![Overview_of_vacation_notes]![YourSubform].Form.Filter = strCriteria 'Set filter criteria
Forms![Overview_of_vacation_notes]![YourSubform].Form.FilterOn = True 'Apply filter.
```

Comment: @jenshon Glad to know.